# ASP is looking for first page module in second page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I have one asp.net mvc 3 application (www.name.com) with custom module added to web.config:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="MyModule" type="Modules.MyModule" />
</modules>
```

When I run from this application second application (www.name.com/Another) I get error:
Could not load type 'Modules.MyModule'. But I don't need this module in second app, only in first. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by [ASP.NET configuration inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx), as www.name.com/Another is a subdirectory of www.name.com it will inherit all of the web.config settings of the www.name.com aswell.

Try adding:

```
<modules>
    <remove name="MyModule" />
</modules>
```

To www.name.com/Another's web.config.